# How to deploy ear file in to artifactory non maven application

Tags: java, ant, artifactory

We are trying to deploy the ear file in to my artifactory for non maven Java project.
here we are building the application using apache ant. please any one can suggest how can i deploy the my ear file in to artifactory using any scripts.writing something in to build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old maven-ant-tasks package to do the upload of the artifact and the pom file.
Check this: http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/

You can use the writepom function to define the pom and than create a target to execute the artifact:deploy task from the package.

It's really an easy setup approach.

Example:

```
<target name="artifactory-deployment">
<artifact_jf:pom id="tmp.pom" groupid="${artifact.groupid}" artifactid="${artifact.name}" version="1.0" packaging="ear" name="${artifact.name}"         />
<artifact_jf:writepom pomRefId="tmp.pom" file="pom.xml"/>
<artifact_jf:deploy file="build/ears/artifact.ear">
    <remoteRepository url="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local">
        <authentication username="artifactory-username" password="artifactory-password" />
    </remoteRepository>
    <pom file="pom.xml" />
</artifact_jf:deploy>
```

Comment: Currently my buiuld.xml file is only creating ear . If you have sample build.xml file for deploy to artifactory please suggest me. Here i'm not understanding what is mypom refid and all.

Comment: where shuild i write groupid and artifactId?

Comment: please check and give me suggetions on this    

 here it is installing ear filein to m2 folder after that 
[artifact:deploy] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
[artifact:deploy]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:deploy] 
[artifact:deploy] A POM element is required to deploy to the repository
[artifact:deploy] 
BUILD FAILED
C:\RAD\WorkspacesV75\WAS70\IafDeploymentSTS9.0\BuildScript\build.xml:50: A POM element is required to deploy to the repository